# how to combine two queries to produce one result in codigniter

Tags: php

this is my query working fine

```
      $offset = ($this->uri->segment(4))?$this->uri->segment(4):0;
        $limit =10;
```

i donn't use $user_id becoz this function uses pagination

```
   $q = "select distinct attandence.user_id ,monthname(date), sum(is_absent) as absents,in_time,out_time , count(date)  as working_days, leave_type , users.f_name ,leave_types.type ,leave_types.leave_type_id , users.l_name ,( select count(leave_type) from attandence where leave_type != 0 and user_id = 4 and month(date) = 10 ) as leave_count  from attandence join users on (users.user_id = attandence.user_id) left join leave_types on(leave_types.leave_type_id = attandence.leave_type) where in_time != '' and out_time != ''  ".$where_condition." GROUP BY attandence.user_id LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ". $offset; 

     $rows = $this->attandence_model->q($q);

     $this->data['Details'] = $rows;
```

in view  i just passed

```
  <? foreach ($Details as $detail){ ?>
  <? } ?>





   Any help is going to be appreciated. :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution your query you can add sub query [Sub query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)

See Example:

```
$q = "select distinct attandence.user_id ,monthname(date), sum(is_absent) as absents,in_time,out_time , count(date)  as working_days, leave_type , users.f_name ,leave_types.type ,leave_types.leave_type_id , users.l_name, (select count(leave_type) from attandence where leave_type != 0 and user_id = 15 and month(date) = 10) as leave_count  from attandence join users on (users.user_id = attandence.user_id) left join leave_types on(leave_types.leave_type_id = attandence.leave_type) where in_time != '' and out_time != ''  ".$where_condition." GROUP BY attandence.user_id LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ". $offset;
```

Comment: Don't wanna use static value user_id = 15 and month(date) = 10 same as above only 
(select count(leave_type) from attandence where leave_type != 0 )
using this it display  leave_count =36

Comment: you can set dynamic user id  user_id = $user_id

Comment: sorry i can't use this dynamic method because i already pass the above query variable in foreach loop

Comment: ok you have passed array in user id so do use  loop  in get user id put in query  place of static user id.

Comment: its working fine only want it to use the user_id and date(month) as the whole query uses here count_leave was  not correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128150/discussion-between-pawan-sen-and-meow).